# How do I add typescript components to existing vuejs project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

Currently I have a few projects in production that are based on Vue cli 3 projects (plain js).

I would like to start using typescript for new components and overtime refactor the current js components and project files to ts.

I have searched around the internet and feel this would be a common problem developers experience as they transition along the frontend/vuejs learning journey. However, I could not find an approach to achieve this without having to convert the project entirely to ts.

Therefore, I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to add typescript using the vue cli 3 (I lack knowledge in webpack), such that my current projects compiling using js and add the ability for new components to be implemented using typescript (lang=“ts”).

Comment: Have you tried a package like this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-class-component
You can make some components class components and implement TS and some not. There are other similar packages as well...

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by using the vue cli to create a ts project, set allowJs in the tsconfig then replaced everything but the main.ts which was updated with a ts equivalent of the main.js.